# Delegate method not called using Singleton

Tags: delegates, singleton, protocols, ios11, swift4

Similar questions have already been asked but they haven't helped. I'm trying to call protocol method declared in `Singleton` class from a view controller but the called method never invokes.

My protocol and class are:

```
import Foundation

protocol ServiceDelegate {
  func serviceData(data: [String: Any])
}

class Service {

private static let sharedInstance = Service()  // singleton object
var delegate: ServiceDelegate?

class func shared() -> Service {
    return sharedInstance
}

func login(postData:String) {

    let url = URL(string: "MY_URL")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let dataBody = postData.data(using:String.Encoding.ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
    request.httpBody = dataBody
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            return
        }
        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let dataArray = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            self.delegate?.serviceData(data: dataArray)   // This is getting called
        }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
}
```

My view controller class where protocol is implemented is:

```
import UIKit

class LoginVC: UIViewController, ServiceDelegate {

var serviceInstance: Service = Service()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    serviceInstance.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func loginBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    let info = "userName=\(String(describing: usernameText.text!))&password=\(String(describing: passwordText.text!))"
    Service.shared().login(postData: info)
}

// This is not getting called:
func serviceData(data: [String : Any]) {
    print(data)
}
```

Is the above implementation correct? Can I use private singleton object to successfully implement protocol method?

Comment: I executed if let delegate = self.delegate {
                //Do your works here
            }else{
                print("The delegate is nil")
            } , But thats coming nil

Comment: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-three-ways-to-pass-data-from-model-to-controller-b47cc72a4336

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating *two* `Service` instances. You should only be using the one returned by `Service.shared()`. That’s the actual *singleton* shared across your app.

In your view controller, replace this line:

```
serviceInstance.delegate = self
```

with:

```
Service.shared().delegate = self
```

And you should also delete this line (i.e., the unnecessary second instance):

```
var serviceInstance: Service = Service()
```